# How to implement a 96 conditions wisely?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time

I'm trying to write a program in c++ which produce a report, which provide a report on the usage by time. Break the time into blocks of quarter of an hour

```
00:00-00:14, 00:15-00:29, …, 23:45-23:59.
```

I should provide number of incidents in each time break. This is my code so far. I appreciate if anyone come up with a solution.

```
string time = word;
size_t found2 = word.find(":");
string tmpH,tmpM;
tmpH = word.substr(0,found2);
tmpM = word.substr((found2+1),word.length());
cout<<"  word=  "<<word<<" tmpH=  "<<tmpH<<"  tmpM=  "<<tmpM<<endl;
int h = atoi(tmpH.c_str());
int m = atoi(tmpM.c_str());
```

////
Input:

```
aa784     pts/30       Fri Mar 28 03:25   still logged in  101.175.22.198
aa784     sshd         Fri Mar 28 03:25   still logged in  101.175.22.198
aa784     pts/30       Fri Mar 28 03:25 - 03:25  (00:00)   101.175.22.198
aa784     sshd         Fri Mar 28 03:25 - 03:25  (00:00)   101.175.22.198
hmb183    sshd         Fri Mar 28 03:24   still logged in  c110-20-244-248.mirnd4.nsw.optusnet.com.au
bkg988    sshd         Fri Mar 28 03:24 - 03:24  (00:00)   139.218.157.100
hmb183    sshd         Fri Mar 28 03:21 - 03:22  (00:01)   c110-20-244-248.mirnd4.nsw.optusnet.com.au
fmm290    pts/43       Fri Mar 28 03:11   still logged in  1002-wan-001.rhw.com.au
fmm290    sshd         Fri Mar 28 03:11   still logged in  1002-wan-001.rhw.com.au
bkg988    sshd         Fri Mar 28 03:09 - 03:09  (00:00)   139.218.157.100
pm554     pts/14       Fri Mar 28 02:22   still logged in  ppp239-204.static.internode.on.net
pm554     sshd         Fri Mar 28 02:22   still logged in  ppp239-204.static.internode.on.net
bkg988    sshd         Fri Mar 28 02:17 - 02:17  (00:00)   139.218.157.100
bkg988    sshd         Fri Mar 28 02:12 - 02:12  (00:00)   139.218.157.100
bkg988    sshd         Fri Mar 28 02:10 - 02:10  (00:00)   139.218.157.100
bx972     pts/12       Fri Mar 28 02:09   still logged in  cpe-121-218-195-236.lnse4.cht.bigpond.net.au
bkg988    sshd         Fri Mar 28 02:07 - 02:07  (00:00)   139.218.157.100
hmb183    sshd         Fri Mar 28 02:05 - 02:06  (00:01)   c110-20-244-248.mirnd4.nsw.optusnet.com.au
bkg988    sshd         Fri Mar 28 02:04 - 02:04  (00:00)   139.218.157.100
```

output:

```
00:00-00:14   10 users logged in
00:15-00:29   15 users logged in
....
23:45-23:59   3 users logged in
```

Therefore I have 4 conditions in an hour which comes to 96 conditions of time?

Comment: Can you give an example of the input you have and the output you're looking for?

Comment: What is exactly your problem and what did you tried?

Comment: The code you show has little to do with your assigment, hasn't it? What have you tried? It's very simple to come up with a loop over the hours and one over every quarter.

Comment: I have added an example. The problem with loop is that it is not only one day. Input is user login for years and initial time is not 00:00. it can be anytime...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can convert each block of hour and minute into minutes , for example 23:45 equals 1095 in minutes. Storing all of these blocks into a list and **sort them by its starting time**.

For each event, convert each event time into number of minute and use **binary search(or linear search)** to search for a block that has **largest starting time less than or equals** to the event time,and that block will be the block this event belong to.

Time complexity to sort is O(1) as there is only few block, and, for all query will be O(n), with n is the number of query.(Binary search in this case can be considered take constant time).

Edit: As you have added another constraint, so , you need to sort all the event by date and time, and for each date, you can use the described approach.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be the best idea instead of conversion to time and checking it the time frame with 96 variables.

Comment: @Bernard , actually you don't need binary search in this case, just a linear search seems good enough :D

Answer (score 1):

Given lines like:

```
bkg988    sshd         Fri Mar 28 02:17 - 02:17  (00:00)   139.218.157.100
```

You can do this:

```
std::string to_month_number(const std::string& name)
{
    return name == "Jan" ? "01/" :
           name == "Feb" ? "02/" :
           ...;
}

typedef std::pair<std::string, int> When;
typedef std::map<When, int> Num_Logins;

Num_Logins num_logins;
std::string user, term, day, month, dom;
int hour, min;
char c;

while (std::cin >> user >> term >> dow >> month >> dom >> hour >> c >> min && c == ':')
{
    if (dom.length() == 1) dom = ' ' + dom; // standardise with for sorting...
    When when = std::make_pair(to_month_number(month) + ' ' + dom, (hour * 60 + min) / 15);
    ++num_logins[when];
}
```

I suspect the actual input will be a bit more complex, with the date being formatted differently when the process started last year or intraday, so you'll need to tune the fields parsed out.  To recreate the time when iterating over `num_logins` to print out results, just:

```
int hour = key->second / 4;
int min = (key->second % 4) * 15;   // 00, 15, 30 or 45
```